How to translate 戳着不动
https://www.51shucheng.net/zhentan/baiyexing/43795.html has 不能一直戳着不动, the problem is that 戳 and 不动 seem to be contradictory.

「戳着」在这里的意思是「站着」，「一直戳着不动」就是「一直站着不动」的意思。不矛盾。参考《汉语大词典》：

戳：竖立；站。梁斌《红旗谱》一：「这座铜钟就在柏树底下，戳在地上有两人高。」郑万隆《年轻的朋友们》八：「瞧瞧，还让您在这儿戳着，快进来喝碗水吧！」

也可以参考《汉英词典》：

戳I.动3〈方〉stand sth. on end:

有话进来说，别在门口儿戳着。
Don't stand in the doorway. Come in if you have something to say.



also see BKRS:戳 ③ 〈方〉竖立；站：把棍子戳起来 | 大伙儿都走了，他一个人还戳在那儿。(7) 竖立的; 站的 [erect; stand]
两边一色戳灯, 照如白昼。 --《红楼梦》

No contradiction there!
不能
cannot / could not
一直
just
戳着
stand
不动
not move
四周没有其他人，
There was nobody around,
友彦不能一直戳着不动。
Yumura could not just stand motionless
他心里盘算着该怎么办，
He was plotting what to do,
应该死心回头吗？
should he just give up and turn away?
但是，
But,
想及早进行“实验”的欲望也很强烈。
(his) desire to carry out "the experiment" at the earliest opportunity was very strong.

Often than not, Chinese words may have more than one meaning, and the meanings can seem contradictory, but they are not if we know the reason the other meanings were derived.
戳:



用硬物尖端触击(poke, stab), 2. 竖立，站立(standstill as a post), 3. 图章(seal).




竖立，站立(stand vertically) - derived from making a rod/stick standing by poking a hole in the ground using one of its heads/ends. (不要戳在那裡 = 不要站在那裡像根棍子)




(蓋)圖章(putting one's seal on, stamp) - usually used together with another word, such as 戳记(countermark) and 郵戳(postmark), to describe the action of stampping.



Note, when using the dictionary, it is imperative to study all the meanings,
and given examples, so as to have a thorough/correct understanding of the word and its uses.
